# My link with rel="shadobox" is showing old image and not my recent image only on internet explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, shadowbox

I have a edit news page with a form, inside form I have this code below to show the actual image of my news.

Im using tim.php to generate thumbnails. And it is working fine, Im having thumbnail of my image, but then I have a link to click and see the original image(not the thumbnail), and when I click in this link "See actual image", Im having an old image and not my recent image. But this only happenins on internet explorer, on google chrome is working fine.

Do you see why this can be happening?

I have this code below inside a form,

```
<div class="viewImage">
     <img src="tim.php?src=../uploads/<?php echo $result['thumb'];?>&h=45" alt="Actual image" title="Actual Image" />  
     <a href="../uploads/<?php echo $result['thumb'];?>" rel="shadowbox">See Actual Image</a>
</div><!--viewcapa-->
```

Comment: Try refreshing the browser `CTRL F5`

Comment: Thanks for your answer RiggsFolly but dont works!

Comment: But If I close internet explorer and then open again..it works. Do you know how to fix this?